# How do I calculate the amount of time between multiple datetimes in multiple rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've done a search but I can't find any that are exactly what I need. I need to be able to calculate the amount of time that someone has been in the building over time in a sql query (T-SQL on SQL Server). The data looks like this:

```
UserId   Clocking        Status
------------------------------
1      01/12/2020 09:00   In
2      01/12/2020 09:12   In
1      01/12/2020 09:25   Out
3      01/12/2020 10:00   In
2      01/12/2020 10:45   Out
3      01/12/2020 13:11   Out 
1      03/12/2020 11:14   In
2      03/12/2020 15:56   In
1      03/12/2020 16:04   Out
2      03/12/2020 17:00   Out
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
UserId  TimeInBuilding
----------------------
1      03:35
2      05:25
3      03:11
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...? Date functins are vendor specific. Also, what if the "in"s and "out"s do not properly interleave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the ins/outs are perfectly interleaved, you can do this by assigning the next "out" time to the "in" time and aggregating:

```
select userid,
       sum(datediff(second, clocking, out_time)) / (60.0 * 60) as decimal_hours
from (select t.*,
             lead(clocking) over (partition by userid order by clocking) as out_time
      from t
     ) t
where status = 'In'
group by userid;
```

You can convert this to HH:MM format using:

```
select userid,
       convert(varchar(5),
               convert(time,
                       dateadd(second,
                               sum(datediff(second, clocking, out_time),
                               0)
                      )
               ) as hhmm
from (select t.*,
             lead(clocking) over (partition by userid order by clocking) as out_time
      from t
     ) t
where status = 'In'
group by userid;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9ebfc01550a1f9229fc9a3a1d91f90cc) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Wow. That's brilliant! Works perfectly. Thanks. Really appreciated.

Comment: Aside: Note that [`time`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is limited to 00:00:00.0000000 through 23:59:59.9999999. If the data includes more than one date that may become a problem.